How to expose a custom module's service as a Twig global?
I have a custom module setup, which I created via the Craft generator. It includes a service and a Twig extension. I'd like to make all of my module's services and methods available via a Twig variable, which it looks like I can do by extending the Twig GlobalsInterface, as per the docs here:
namespace mynamespace\myplugin\twig;

use Craft;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\Extension\GlobalsInterface;
use mynamespace\myplugin\MyPlugin;

class Extension extends AbstractExtension implements GlobalsInterface
{

    public function getGlobals(): array
    {
        // Keys are variable names!
         return [
            'myPlugin' => MyPlugin::getInstance(),
        ];
    }
}

However, this is not working for me, and I believe it's because the example is for a plugin, not a module, and IIRC calling MyModule::get_instance() does not work like MyPlugin::get_instance().
How do I adapt this code to work for my custom module?
My current (non-working) code for the Twig extension:
namespace modules\amphibian\web\twig;

use Craft;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\Extension\GlobalsInterface;
use modules\amphibian;

class Extension extends AbstractExtension implements GlobalsInterface
{

    public function getGlobals(): array
    {
        // Keys are variable names!
         return [
            'amphibian' => Amphibian::getInstance(),
        ];
    }
}

My service, also added via the generator, is called Utility, and I have a function inside named test().
Calling {{ amphibian.utility.test() }} yields a Variable "amphibian" does not exist. runtime error.

Is your Twig extension registered in the main Module class for all requests? It sounds like it's not being initialized!

Yup, this is tyake care of by the generator. Inside of init() I have Craft::$app->view->registerTwigExtension(new AmphibianTwig()).

Huh! And your module is present in the bootstrap array in config/app.php?

Yup, it is, along with my service loaded as a component.

An alternative approach is to extend the global craft variable, by adding your amphibian module as a property on it.
In your main module class' init() method (this example assumes your amphibian module's main class is MyModule):
Event::on(
    CraftVariable::class,
    CraftVariable::EVENT_INIT,
    static function(Event $e) {
        /** @var CraftVariable $variable */
        $variable = $e->sender;
        $variable->set('amphibian', MyModule::getInstance());
    }
);

In a Twig template:
{{ craft.amphibian.utility.test() }}


Thanks Mats, I'll try this approach.

This also did not work for me, BUT, I ended up attaching my custom fuction as a behavior and that did work. Not sure why the other approaches did not.

@DerekHogue Weird! I've successfully used both approaches exemplified here in the past... Great that you figured out something else though, if it works it works!
